# Match str to selector

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items in a list

> Item one
>
> Item two
>
> Another item-one

Also I get a variable from URL in the following format:

```
Item-two
```

What is the best way to select the matching item?

For now I take the URL variable and strip hyphens to compound into a single word.

```
$item= str_replace('-', '', $_GET['item']);
```

So, now, do I need to iterate through the list and also remove spaces/dashes and match?

```
var getItem = '".$item."';    

if (getTerm != '') {

    $('#itemList li').each(function() {
        var that = $(this).replace(/[\\. ,:-]+/g,'');
        if (getTerm  == that) {
            // found selector -- do something
        }
    });

} else {
    // do something else
}
```

It loks right to me but I'm not getting expected results of finding the match element... What am I missing?

Comment: Are mixing JavaScript and PHP? Don't think `var getItem = '".$item."';   ` will work

Comment: It will if it's in a document that gets parsed by php and is formatted properly as php outputting javascript. I suspect the issue is that regexp and the incorrect usage of `.replace`

Comment: Yes, that var is working fine. I set it earlier in my page and strip hyphens with PHP. It produces something like: "Itemtwo". The question I have is using .each() the way to go. I need to find the first matching element only.

Comment: Message to down-voters: care to offer a solution?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getTerm` is working correctly in the mixed js php paradigm. You should be able to find the element like so:

```
// instead of "Itemtwo" or "Item-two" 
// lets make it match exactly as in "Item two"
getTerm = getTerm.replace('-',' '); 

$('#itemList li').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (getTerm  == that.text()) {
        that.css('color','red'); // for example
    }
});
```

Comment: That would have been easier, but all the items in URL have hyphens and just a few of the items in the list have that, while most don't. But your example helped me see what I missed: .text()  Thanks!